# filling listview using cursoradapter

Tags: android, android-listview, simplecursoradapter

i implemented Custom cursor adapter in my listview. but the listview is always null. 
Let me explain my codes:

```
    OfflineAdapter offlineadapter = new OfflineAdapter(ctx, null);
    listview.setAdapter(offlineadapter);
```

There's nothing really to explain Here.
Moving into my offlineadapter Class:

```
public class OfflineAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    public com.androidarabia.lazylist.ImageLoader imageLoader;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public OfflineAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c);

        imageLoader = new com.androidarabia.lazylist.ImageLoader(
                context.getApplicationContext());
```

Initializing...

```
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pricelist, parent, false);
    bindView(v, context, cursor);
    return v;
```

}

Inflating layout...

```
@Override
public void bindView(View v, Context context, Cursor c) {
    try {
        String title = c.getString(c
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(LebanonSamsung.KEY_PHONENAME));
        String date = c.getString(c
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(LebanonSamsung.KEY_MODELNUMBER));
        String imagePath = c.getString(c
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(LebanonSamsung.KEY_PRICE));
        String deletion = c.getString(c
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(LebanonSamsung.KEY_URL));

        TextView title_text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
            title_text.setText(title);


        TextView date_text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.modelnumber);
            date_text.setText(date);


        ImageView item_image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(deletion, item_image);

        TextView del_image = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.details);
        del_image.setText(imagePath);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Yes, the database isn't null at all, i ran a check to view if it's null but it's not!
What can i do? the listview is always empty. what i'm doing wrong??? Thanks!

**

---

**UPDATE**
i noticed that im not closing cursor. 
Here's my database codes:

```
public class LebanonSamsung {
    public static final String KEY_PHONENAME = "phone_name";
    public static final String KEY_PRICE = "phone_price";
    public static final String KEY_MODELNUMBER = "phone_modelnumber";
    public static String prefName = "SecretFile";
    static SharedPreferences prefs;
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_URL = "phone_picurl";
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "PriceListDatabasesamsunglebanon";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static DbHelper ourHelper;
    private static Context ourContext;
    private static SQLiteDatabase mDb;
    private static final String SQLITE_SAMSUNGLEBANON = "SamsungLebanon";
    public static final String DATABASE_CREATESAMSUNGLEBANON = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
            + SQLITE_SAMSUNGLEBANON
            + " ("
            + KEY_ROWID
            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + KEY_PHONENAME
            + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + KEY_URL
            + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + KEY_PRICE
            + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_MODELNUMBER + " TEXT NOT NULL);";

    private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public DbHelper(Context ourContext) {
            super(ourContext, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            prefs = ourContext.getSharedPreferences(prefName,
                    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            arg0.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATESAMSUNGLEBANON);

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            arg0.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + SQLITE_SAMSUNGLEBANON);

            onCreate(arg0);
        }
    }

    public LebanonSamsung(Context onNavigationListener) {
        ourContext = onNavigationListener;
    }

    public LebanonSamsung open() throws SQLException {
        ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
        mDb = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        ourHelper.close();
    }

    public boolean deletesamsung() {

        int doneDelete = 0;
        doneDelete = mDb.delete(SQLITE_SAMSUNGLEBANON, null, null);
        Log.w("error bi deleting l table", Integer.toString(doneDelete));
        return doneDelete > 0;
    }

    public long createEntrySamsung(String phonename, String phoneprice,
            String modelnumber, String url) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_PHONENAME, phonename);
        cv.put(KEY_PRICE, phoneprice);
        cv.put(KEY_MODELNUMBER, modelnumber);
        cv.put(KEY_URL, url);

        return mDb.insert(SQLITE_SAMSUNGLEBANON, null, cv);

    }

    public Cursor listsamsung() {

        Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(SQLITE_SAMSUNGLEBANON,
                new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_PHONENAME, KEY_PRICE,
                        KEY_MODELNUMBER, KEY_URL }, null, null, null, null,
                null);

        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }

    public void insertsamsung() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        new insertentries().execute("");

    }

    public class insertentries extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

        protected void onPreExecute() {
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            InputStream isr = null;
            String result = "";
            try {
                String url;
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String range = prefs.getString("range", "1");
                String sortby = prefs.getString("filtering", "ByDate");
                url = "there's a url";
                Log.e("url", url);
                HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost(url);
                HttpResponse resposne = httpclient.execute(httpost);
                HttpEntity entity = resposne.getEntity();
                isr = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(isr, "UTF-8"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                isr.close();
                result = sb.toString();

                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    createEntrySamsung(json.getString("PhoneName"),
                            json.getString("PhonePrice"),
                            json.getString("ModelNumber"),
                            json.getString("imageurl"));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting Result " + e.toString());
            }

            return result;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        }
    }
}Anybody
```

?
LOGCAT:

```
08-06 17:13:10.753: E/SQLiteDatabase(532): close() was never explicitly called on database '/data/data/com.androidarabia.phones/databases/PriceListDatabasesamsunglebanon' 
08-06 17:13:10.753: E/SQLiteDatabase(532): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
08-06 17:13:10.753: E/SQLiteDatabase(532):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1943)
08-06 17:13:10.753: E/SQLiteDatabase(532):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1007)
08-06 17:13:10.753: E/SQLiteDatabase(532):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:986)
08-06 17:13:10.753: E/SQLiteDatabase(532):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1051)
08-06 17:13:10.753: E/SQLiteDatabase(532):  at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:770)
08-06 17:13:10.753: E/SQLiteDatabase(532):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:221)
08-06 17:13:10.753: E/SQLiteDatabase(532):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:157)
08-06 17:13:10.753: E/SQLiteDatabase(532):  at com.androidarabia.databases.LebanonSamsung.open(LebanonSamsung.java:81)
08-06 17:13:10.753: E/SQLiteDatabase(532):  at com.androidarabia.drawer.SamsungLB.onCreateView(SamsungLB.java:65)
08-06 17:13:10.753: E/SQLiteDatabase(532):  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1478)
08-06 17:13:10.753: E/SQLiteDatabase(532):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
08-06 17:13:10.753: E/SQLiteDatabase(532):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
08-06 17:13:10.753: E/SQLiteDatabase(532):  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
08-06 17:13:10.753: E/SQLiteDatabase(532):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1460)
08-06 17:13:10.753: E/SQLiteDatabase(532):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
08-06 17:13:10.753: E/SQLiteDatabase(532):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
08-06 17:13:10.753: E/SQLiteDatabase(532):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
08-06 17:13:10.753: E/SQLiteDatabase(532):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
08-06 17:13:10.753: E/SQLiteDatabase(532):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
08-06 17:13:10.753: E/SQLiteDatabase(532):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
08-06 17:13:10.753: E/SQLiteDatabase(532):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:594)
08-06 17:13:10.753: E/SQLiteDatabase(532):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:376)
08-06 17:13:10.753: E/SQLiteDatabase(532):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
08-06 17:13:10.753: E/SQLiteDatabase(532):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
08-06 17:13:10.753: E/SQLiteDatabase(532):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
08-06 17:13:10.753: E/SQLiteDatabase(532):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
08-06 17:13:10.753: E/SQLiteDatabase(532):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
08-06 17:13:10.753: E/SQLiteDatabase(532):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
08-06 17:13:10.753: E/SQLiteDatabase(532):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
08-06 17:13:10.753: E/SQLiteDatabase(532):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
08-06 17:13:10.753: E/SQLiteDatabase(532):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
08-06 17:13:10.753: E/SQLiteDatabase(532):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
08-06 17:13:10.753: E/SQLiteDatabase(532):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:812)
08-06 17:13:10.753: E/SQLiteDatabase(532):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
08-06 17:13:10.753: E/SQLiteDatabase(532):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
08-06 17:13:10.753: E/SQLiteDatabase(532):  at com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.CustomViewAbove.onMeasure(CustomViewAbove.java:456)
08-06 17:13:10.753: E/SQLiteDatabase(532):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
08-06 17:13:10.753: E/SQLiteDatabase(532):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:594)
08-06 17:13:10.753: E/SQLiteDatabase(532):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:376)
08-06 17:13:10.753: E/SQLiteDatabase(532):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
08-06 17:13:10.753: E/SQLiteDatabase(532):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
08-06 17:13:10.753: E/SQLiteDatabase(532):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
08-06 17:13:10.753: E/SQLiteDatabase(532):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2092)
08-06 17:13:10.753: E/SQLiteDatabase(532):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
08-06 17:13:10.753: E/SQLiteDatabase(532):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1064)
08-06 17:13:10.753: E/SQLiteDatabase(532):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
08-06 17:13:10.753: E/SQLiteDatabase(532):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-06 17:13:10.753: E/SQLiteDatabase(532):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-06 17:13:10.753: E/SQLiteDatabase(532):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
08-06 17:13:10.753: E/SQLiteDatabase(532):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-06 17:13:10.753: E/SQLiteDatabase(532):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-06 17:13:10.753: E/SQLiteDatabase(532):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
08-06 17:13:10.753: E/SQLiteDatabase(532):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
08-06 17:13:10.753: E/SQLiteDatabase(532):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-06 17:13:10.793: E/System(532): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer
08-06 17:13:10.875: E/System(532): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Don't have database lock!
08-06 17:13:10.875: E/System(532):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.verifyLockOwner(SQLiteDatabase.java:2090)
08-06 17:13:10.875: E/System(532):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$1.entryRemoved(SQLiteDatabase.java:2182)
08-06 17:13:10.875: E/System(532):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$1.entryRemoved(SQLiteDatabase.java:2178)
08-06 17:13:10.875: E/System(532):  at android.util.LruCache.trimToSize(LruCache.java:197)
08-06 17:13:10.875: E/System(532):  at android.util.LruCache.evictAll(LruCache.java:285)
08-06 17:13:10.875: E/System(532):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.deallocCachedSqlStatements(SQLiteDatabase.java:2143)
08-06 17:13:10.875: E/System(532):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.closeClosable(SQLiteDatabase.java:1126)
08-06 17:13:10.875: E/System(532):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.finalize(SQLiteDatabase.java:1914)
08-06 17:13:10.875: E/System(532):  at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:182)
08-06 17:13:10.875: E/System(532):  at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:168)
08-06 17:13:10.875: E/System(532):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: it would be great help if you could post your code for the fragments.

Comment: 1. error: newView doesn't need to call bindView
2. we are missing the code that sets the cursor, are you calling swapCursor sowewhere? beacuse new OfflineAdapter(ctx, null); says you are setting a null cursor.

Comment: 1. ok i will remove that. 
2. no. i didn't see that in tutorials??/

Comment: @Raanan what to do next?

Comment: You need to get a Cursor from your DB (maybe using listsamsung() ?) and put it in the adapter, either when instantiating it or after by using swapCursor command.

Comment: @Raanan can you show me a demo?

Answer (score 0):

This line the second value should be a Cursor retrived from your DB

```
OfflineAdapter offlineadapter = new OfflineAdapter(ctx, null);
```

Try:

```
LebanonSamsung lSamsung= new LebanonSamsung(ctx).open();
Cursor c = lSamsung.listsamsung();
OfflineAdapter offlineadapter = new OfflineAdapter(ctx, c);
```

Another issue you might have is that you are populating your DB with a background task, where are you calling "insertsamsung()"? , you should consider setting the adapter to your list in the onPostExecute function.

Comment: Try adding a Log line:
Log.v("TAG","Cursor result:" + c.getCount());

Comment: If you look at your LogCat which you can find in the DDMS view in eclipse, you should be able to see if you are getting results in the cursor.

Comment: Yes thanks! but one problem, sometimes the listview go filled sometimes not. 
When it fills i get this error:
08-06 21:15:44.041: E/log_tag(10501): Error converting Result java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase: /data/data/com.androidarabia.phones/databases/Database

what to do????

Comment: To answer that I would need to see the Activity/Fragment code. You are probably calling the open() in a function that repeats and not calling close() at all.

Side note, If you find the answer helpful it is nice if you also vote it up. (common courtesy as it also increases the reputation of the people that assist you.)